# uncheck check box with c# wbrbrower control and GetElementsByTagName

Tags: c#, checkbox

there is a webform with a checkbox

input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="1" checked="checked"

using the webbrowser control and WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

how can i uncheck the damm checkbox

My try

HtmlElementCollection elements4 = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

```
                    foreach (HtmlElement element4 in elements4)
                    {
                        if (element4.Name == "subscribe")
                        {


                            element4.SetAttribute("subscribe", "false");
                           element4.InvokeMember("unchecked");

                          //  element4.checked = false;// doesn't even exist this line


                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SetAttribute` to set the `checked` attribute. In this case:

```
element4.SetAttribute("checked", "false");
```

`SetAttribute` accepts two arguments, the name of the attribute you want to set, and a value. You can look at the MDC for a list of all of the other properties you can set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement

Comment: also i just tried this 
element4.SetAttribute("value", "0");
same, it doesn't work

Comment: You need to ensure that you are calling SetAttribute once the page has fulled loaded, usually through the DocumentComplete event.